# Adding touchupinside to a programmatically created button, and submitting a NSDate to a textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The problem I'm coming across is that I'm unsure how to add touchupinside to the below code for the save date button. I'm just trying to launch a UIDatePicker and submit a date into a text field, and then dismiss it.

So I don't know how to link this programmatically created button to the datePicker method. Not only that but, I haven't used UIDatePicker before, so reading this into a textfield I'm a bit fuzzy on. The text field is dateFieldText.

Once the user taps Save Date then the UIDatePicker should be dismissed.

Thanks for the help. This issue is a bit more complicated for me.

```
      - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
        {
            sender.delegate = self;
                if([sender isEqual:dateFieldText])
                {
                    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                               initWithTitle:@"Save Date"
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                               target:self
                                               action:@selector(datePicker)];

                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;

            }
            else{
                UIBarButtonItem *submitButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                               initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                               target:self
                                               action:@selector(datePicker)];
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = submitButton;

            }  
        }


    -(IBAction)datePicker
    {
        UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(saveDate)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self.dateFieldText setInputView:datePicker];
    }

    // I haven't made the saveDate method yet...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things wired up incorrectly. You need to make the date picker the text field's inputView at the point you create the text field, not after the user taps a button that isn't added until the user puts focus on the text field.

You also don't need a Done button and a Save Date button. Either have a single Done button or have a Save and a Cancel button.

You are also going to need to implement the `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate method to remove any buttons that you add.

Your `saveDate` method will need to update the text field's text with the currently selected date (after converting the date to a string with an `NSDateFormatter`).

The action for your Done/Save/Cancel button(s) (whatever you end up doing) simply needs to call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field. This will dismiss the date picker. The button actions may also need to save off or revert the date's value as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. This helps.